# Line element doesn't get properly focus when selected

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a .xaml file, which looks like:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:lineElement="clr-namespace:...LineElement"
                    xmlns:mvvmWpfBehavior="clr-namespace:Gno.Libraries.WpfMvvm.Behaviors.Focus;assembly=Gno.Libraries.WpfMvvm">

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type lineElement:LineElementViewModel}">

            <Grid>
                <Line Stroke="DarkBlue"  X1="{Binding PX1}" Y1="{Binding PY1}" X2="{Binding PX2}" Y2="{Binding PY2}" 
                  StrokeThickness="3" Visibility="Visible" Stretch="Fill">                        
                </Line>

            </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If I have set the coordinates in LineElementViewModel.cs as: PX1=0, PY1=0, PX2=150, PY2=0, I get the view:

[image]

with proper focus selection as you can see.

If I change the coordinates to: PX1=0, PY1=0, PX2=0, PY2=150, I get the view:

[image]

which is behaving exactly as I want. you can see that the focus is selected appropriately.

The problem comes when I resize or stretch (I am able to do since I use `Stretch="Fill"`) the line like this:

[image]

When I change the X1, Y1 etc. coordinates like before to make it vertical, the focus when i select the Line element doesn't get updated.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem, my focus indicator changes correctly... What's `LineElement`? Why aren't you using `Line.RenderTransform`?

Comment: The above behaviour was happening when I used binding on X1, Y1.. tags. If I bind the Angle element, and Instead use <Line.RenderTransform> then the selection box does even work worse. When the Line gets changed from horizontal to vertical, the selection doesn't even change.

Comment: Still can't reproduce... Maybe you could post screenshots of your actual application? Tell us which values of X1, Y1 or Angle are you trying out and what do you expect on each case?

Comment: I have now modified my question, so you can follow better :)